# Error correction : While I am doing the house works I like to listen to music on the radio

Tags: exam-questions

> While I am doing the house works I like to listen to music on the radio.

This sentence is from an error spotting exercise. Which is  the correct way to correct the above given sentence?

Do I need to replace *works* with *work* or replace *to listen* with *listening* ?

Comment: "I like" can be complemented either by infinitive (to listen) or by the -ing form (listening).  *I like listening to the radio. I like to listen to the radio.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo since first clause was in "-ing"(doing)I thought  it was better to use -ing in second as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct term is not *house works* but *[housework](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/housework)*, what you do to keep your home clean.

Comment: Isn't the second correction also required ?